# Оценить цвет предмета

Tags: python, opencv, color, rgb

Необходимо оценить цвет предмета. Например - связки бананов. Конечно, кожура бабана в разных местах имеет разный цвет - от зеленого (через отттенки желтого) до коричневого. Поэтому вырежем бэкграунд и оценим "средний" цвет всех пикселей картинки.
Ничего лучшего не приходит в голову, как перевести картинку из формата RGB в HSV и потом, например, взять среднеквадратичное значение составляющей 'H' для всех пикселей.

```
def rms_color_estimation(input_path, output_path):
    modified_image = bg_remove3(input_path, output_path)
    img_without_bg = cv2.imread(modified_image)
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_without_bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h, s, l = cv2.split(hsv_img)
    height, width = np.shape(h)
    sum_h = 0
    amount_h = 0
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            value_h = h[i, j]
            if value_h > 0:
                amount_h = amount_h + 1
                sum_h = ((value_h * 2) ** 2) + sum_h
    RMS_h = (sum_h / amount_h) ** 0.5
```

- bg_remove3(input_path, output_path) - функция удаляющая бэкграунд на изображении

По идее, по мере того, как бананы будут созревать, среднеквадратичное значение составляющей 'H' будет изменяться от зеленого (120) к желтому (60) и далее к красному (0).
Но есть сомнения, что оценка цвета, только по составляющей "H" даст адекватную картину изменения цвета.
Коллеги, может быть, кто-нибудь решал подобную задачу, что скажете?
[image: Бананы без бэкграунда]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно попробовать так: перевести в HSV, затем выбрать максимально насыщенный пиксель, или лучше 90-ый процентиль по насыщенности (канал S) и использовать его как порог для маски. По этой маске посчитать среднее в канале H.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но для 90 процентиля - результат не очень хороший, сильно завышает значение "среднего" значения составляющей 'H'. Для 35 процентиля результат почти такой же, как и для всех пикселей.